# notepad++ how to switch nppftp window with keyboard?

Tags: notepad++, hotkeys

I have to work on different ftp servers so I use notepad++ and nppftp. It's simple, fast and free, but I can't find hotkey to switch from text tab to nppftp window and back. Is there a way to switch from one tab to another without using mouse?

Illustration: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gd1gH.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch to the NppFTP window using a keyboard shortcut, by adding a shortcut for the `Focus NppFTP Window` option.

To do this, open up the Shortcut Mapper (`Settings -> Shortcut Mapper`), then click `Plugin Commands` and scroll down to the option.

You can then switch back to the other view by defining a shortcut for the `Focus on Another View` option, available from the `Main Menu` options under Shortcut Mapper.

(There's also the `Move to Other View` option too if you need it).

Comment: You're welcome. As far as I can tell, basically anything that you can click in the menus, you can add a keyboard shortcut for.